# Swift: Get max value for key in array of dictionaries

Tags: swift, collections

I have an array containing dictionaries.

```
let arr = [["test":1], ["test":2], ["test":3], ["test":4]]
```

I now need to get the one dictionary that contains the highest value for the key "test" (without iterating through everything). I was thinking about `filter(_:)` but this will only filter out. `map(_:)` also does not work as I need to filter and not to map.

There's an example how to get the key with the highest value in a dictionary but this does not work in this case.

```
let hues = ["Heliotrope": 296, "Coral": 16, "Aquamarine": 156]
let greatestHue = hues.max { a, b in a.value < b.value }
print(greatestHue)
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `hues` is a dictionary, `arr` is an array of dictionaries

Answer (score 1):

You can use `max` much like in your example.

```
let arr = [["test":1], ["test":4], ["test":3], ["test":2]]
print(arr.max { $0["test"]! < $1["test"]! })
```

This gives the dictionary with the highest value.

Of course the use of `!` is bad unless it is guaranteed that each dictionary really has a `"text"` key.

Also note that using `max` will still result in the entire array being iterated. You can't avoid that unless your dictionaries are always sorted by the value. Then in that case simply use `last` instead of `max`.